# Masking or hiding the path to a background image

Tags: php, javascript, css, .htaccess

I'm displaying pieces of an image in a large grid created from divs. I'm using the background-image and background-position to display portions of the image. The problem I'm running in to is that a user can simply open up firebug and see the entire image (which defeats the purpose of the game).

I've attempted to mask the path using a php script as the URL but if the user navigates to the php file, they can still see the image. It would appear that anything I do with the CSS is entirely client side so denying everything outside the localhost in my .htaccess won't work.

Any suggestions?

The over arching goal is to have an automated way to split and display pieces of the image into a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deliver the whole image to the browser, the browser holds the image and has every right to show it to a user.  I don't think you can prevent the browser from showing it.  I'm afraid you will have to deliver the image in pieces, or perhaps write your whole game using `<canvas>` and play around with images as pixel data. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Ray! I figured out that PHP has an image processing and GD library that will allow you to programmaticly copy sections of an image. Instead of creating divs, I'm simply going to cut sections of the image out and only display the ones that have a flag set in the database. Not the most elegant solution but it's effective =P